# ng-include not working in famo.us-angular - not due to missing double quotes

Tags: angularjs, famo.us, famous-angular

I'm working on a hybrid mobile app using famo.us-angular. I'm trying to include a partial/template in my 'index.html' like so:

```
<fa-surface class="content">
    <div ng-include src="'test.html'"></div>
</fa-surface>
```

Double quotes are there, there's no 404 for the file and my 'test.html' contains only this:

```
<p>test</p>
```

After hours of googling and looking here I believe this should work but I get the following error from console.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at angular.min.js:217
    at angular.min.js:51
    at $get.h (angular.min.js:52)
    at l (angular.min.js:56)
    at angular.min.js:217
    at angular.min.js:112
    at l.$get.l.$eval (angular.min.js:126)
    at l.$get.l.$digest (angular.min.js:123)
    at l.$get.l.$apply (angular.min.js:126)
    at l (angular.min.js:81)
```

If I take out the 'ng-include' line the error goes away. Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was due to using a newer version of AngularJS than the one specified as required by famous-angular (1.2.26). Hours of my life wasted and only myself to blame... -.- Well, maybe it helps someone else in the future.